# Regex - Pattern Matching in Shell

Tags: shell

I am trying to match a pattern and extract the values that comes after it. I have used below regex pattern matchching, it it dint help me. No values got extracted as I got blank value when I echoed it.

Someone let me know what mistake I made.

Sample regex:

```
class="remove_link_style">Site Issue - Please check</a></td><td>    
  <ahref="/0051043899"class="remove_link_style">Working</a></td><td>  
  <ahref="/0051043899"class="remove_link_style">
```

patten used: `text=$(echo "class="remove_link_style">Site Issue - Please check</a></td><td><ahref="/0051043899"class="remove_link_style">Working</a></td><td><ahref="/0051043899"class="remove_link_style">" | grep -o --perl-regexp "(?class="remove_link_style")[a-zA-Z0-9_]+"")`

I also wanted to extract the string that comes after `class="remove_link_style"` but before `</a></td><td>`

Comment: your sample data looks incomplete. Did you want a `<a href="..." ` before the first `class`? Good luck.

Comment: Is your data in a single line or do each of the `?class="remove_link_style"` appear in separate lines?

Comment: @rahul : I edited in line breaks, just to make sense of the data. I regret that now, but I don't see a way to roll back to the original msg. Doah!

Comment: @rahul: its a single line.

Comment: @user3624000 . Thanks . I've posted some suggestions and a possible answer. You can take a look at that.

Answer (score 1):

I think you would find a lot of references and advice not to parse XML with bash tools like `grep/sed/awk` . With this context, I would advise using any of the parsing tools like http://xmlsoft.org/xmllint.html or http://xmlstar.sourceforge.net/doc/xmlstarlet.txt . But if you'd like to quickly extract the contents, you can combine `grep` and `cut` as below.

```
echo 'class="remove_link_style">GB|Trekkinn-UK|Manualcrawlrequest|1</a></td><td><ahref="/0051043899"class="remove_link_style">WorkInProgress</a></td><td><ahref="/0051043899"class="remove_link_style">' | grep -Eo 'style"[^<>]*>[^<>]+' | cut -f2 -d">"
```

This prints out:

```
GB|Trekkinn-UK|Manualcrawlrequest|1
WorkInProgress
```

EDIT : As per OP's ask, store the output into an array.

If you need the output to be stored in an array, you need to set the IFS since you have white spaces in your elements.

```
IFS=$'\n'
result=($(echo 'class="remove_link_style">Site Issue - Please check</a></td><td><ahref="/0051043899"class="remove_link_style">Working</a></td><td><ahref="/0051043899"class="remove_link_style">' | grep -Eo 'style"[^<>]*>[^<>]+' | cut -f2 -d">"))
unset IFS

for i in "${result[@]}"; do echo $i; done
Site Issue - Please check
Working
```

Comment: shall the above output each can be assigned to each variable..? Say.. `$issue` will carry `Site Issue - Please Check` and `$status` willy carry `Working`?? Let me know any link I can learn through..

Comment: @user3624000 . Since the elements are dynamic, it's better to store them in an array and print them out as needed. Because you may not necessarily know the first one is an issue and the second one is success. You can iterate through the elements of the array and decide what action to take accordingly.